# $L^1$ norm of a function is greater than the norm of its root

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Edit: My friend helped me to solve this, and now it is solved for me. We must first separate the simple cases, the only serious case is when $\sum_{i=0}^n |f_i|$ and $\alpha$ are both strictly greater than $1$.

Let $L/K$ be an extension of local fields. and let $|.|_L$ be the absolute value on $L$. Suppose we have $K[x] \ni f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n(x-\alpha_i)$ for $\alpha_i$'s in $L$. I want to show that $|\alpha| < \sum_{i=0}^n |f_i|,$ for every root $\alpha$ of $f$, where $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n f_ix^i$. It is about an hour that I stuck in it without no progress, what's make it worser is that I don't have even a raw idea.

Comment: Could you post the solution here? Thanks!

Comment: @Tengu I see your comment just few minutes ago, $$|\alpha^n| = |(\alpha^n+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f_i\alpha^i)-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(f_i\alpha^i)| = |f(\alpha)-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(f_i\alpha^i)| \leq |f(\alpha)| + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}|f_i\alpha^i| = |0| + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}|f_i||\alpha^i| \leq 0 + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}|f_i||\alpha^{n-1}| = |\alpha^{n-1}|\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}|f_i| = |\alpha^{n-1}|(\sum_{i=0}^{n}|f_i|-1) \leq |\alpha^{n-1}|(\sum_{i=0}^{n}|f_i|),$$

now divide by $|\alpha^{n-1}|$.

Comment: @NeoTheComputer: In your computation there is one step where you use $\lvert \alpha^i\rvert \le \lvert \alpha^{n-1}\rvert$, which is only true for $\lvert \alpha\rvert \ge 1$, right? Also, we were meant to show a sharp inequality (but your last $\le$ can be replaced by $<$).

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg If $|\alpha |< 1$, then clearly it is smaller than $1+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} |f_i|=\sum_{i=0}^n |f_i|$. Yes you are right, I noticed that, but I can not change that comment. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @NeoTheComputer Very nice! Also I guess that the inequality holds not necessarily for local fields $L/K$ but arbitrary field/ring with metric space on it.

Comment: @Tengu exactly, my tags (algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory) are misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m := \max \lvert \alpha_i \rvert$, and let $ r \in \{1, .., n\}$ be the number of $\alpha_i$'s such that $\lvert \alpha_i \rvert = m$. Then note that by the ultrametric maximum principle, $\lvert f_{n-r} \rvert = m^r$. Hence

$$ \sum \lvert f_i \rvert \ge \lvert f_n \rvert + \lvert f_{n-r} \rvert = 1+m^r > m $$

(the last inequality is true for any real $m \ge 0$), which by definition is $\ge \lvert \alpha_i \rvert$ for all $i$.